# Stored Proc Last execution date SQL

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am creating a new stored proc.  Is there a way to find out the last time my stored procedure was executed? Every time I execute it? SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` system view to find out the last time your sp was executed:

```
SELECT  b.name, 
        a.last_execution_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats a 
INNER JOIN sys.objects b 
    ON a.object_id = b.object_id 
WHERE DB_NAME(a.database_ID) = 'YourDatabase'
AND b.name = 'YourSp';
```

Comment: I am still having issue getting any results back.  I have been on a similar path using the sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats.  Just can't seem to get results back.

Comment: Are you seeing blank results

Comment: Yes, only column headers

Comment: Yes, I added my database and = 'YourDatabase'
and my SP where AND b.name = 'YourSp';

Comment: Not only that, you can try to append the database as a prefix of both views: `FROM YourDatabase.sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`

Comment: Tried the append, still no result.  I appreciate your help though.

Comment: remove the schema in the `b.name`, it should be just `b.Name = 'usp_Data'`

Comment: High FIVE!  Thank you so much!